# A thicker ProgressBar in WP7, how?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, progress-bar

im making an app who have a counter and a progressbar representing the time left, so if the counter reaches its 50%, the progressbar value is 50. So far so good, I make a progressbar animation of counter total and go.

My question is: How can I make the progressbar thicker? The line itself is too small and the "principal attraction" of my app is the progressbar and I want to make it bigger. Have I to make a template and using another control? (Like using a rectangle visually). I tried changing the progressbar to a rectangle but I don't know how to fill the 60% (e.g) of the rectangle.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done in the progress bar's style.

In the default progress bar's style, you need to

- Add a Height to ProgressBar style,
  say 30.
- Increase the Height of two Rectangles
  ProgressBarTrack and
  ProgressBarIndicator to 24. They are
  inside the ProgressBar's ControlTemplate.
- Increase the Height of
  HorizontalThumb to 24. It's inside
  the PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle.
- In PhoneProgressBarSliderThumb
  ConttrolTemplate, increase both the
  Rectangle's Width and Height to 24.

Here is all styles just in case.:)

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PhoneProgressBarSliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="24" IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="24"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle" TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="3000"/>
        <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Value" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                    <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False">
                        <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalTrackLargeChangeDecreaseRepeatButton" Grid.Column="0" Height="0" Template="{x:Null}"/>
                            <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="24" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderThumb}"/>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalTrackLargeChangeIncreaseRepeatButton" Grid.Column="2" Height="0" Template="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ProgressBarStyle1" TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Determinate"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                    <Storyboard Duration="00:00:04.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DeterminateRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider1">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="1000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="2000"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="3000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider2">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="1000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="2000"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="3000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider3">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="1000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="2000"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="3000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider4">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="1000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="2000"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="3000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider5">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="1000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="2000"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="3000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider1">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider2">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider3">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider4">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider5">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="DeterminateRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Visible">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="ProgressBarTrack" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="24" Opacity="0.1"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="ProgressBarIndicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="IndeterminateRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Grid>
                                <Slider x:Name="Slider1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                                <Slider x:Name="Slider2" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                                <Slider x:Name="Slider3" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                                <Slider x:Name="Slider4" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                                <Slider x:Name="Slider5" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Easy as pie... A question: Why we need the two last changes too? (The thumb ones). Changing the height of the rectangles makes the trick.

Comment: i guess they are for the dot loading progress bar, you can leave them as they are if you don't need them, i just thought better make them consistent. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
<ProgressBar Width="300" Background="White" Foreground="Red" Height="28" Margin="78,0"   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform ScaleY="-5"/>
    </ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
</ProgressBar>
```

Comment: Perfect (and much simpler) solution!