# Increase size of Dots in Progress bar windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, progress-bar

I wanted to display Progress bar Ellipse more that its Default size like this : [increase height of indeterminate progress dot size](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/eb2bfe81-e79c-4ace-96dc-975d925e5108/increase-height-of-indeterminate-progress-dot-size?forum=winappswithhtml5).

I have gone through goggling and  many Questions and Post of blogs but could not find any Solution

Already seen this also but not working in my case:

1. [The high performance ProgressBar for Windows Phone
   (“PerformanceProgressBar”)](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/)
2. [A thicker ProgressBar in WP7,
       how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847678/a-thicker-progressbar-in-wp7-how)

Comment: Why aren't these links working for you?

Comment: i have tried that links first link xmlns:unsupported="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Unsupported" has older version of silverlight toolkit so its not working in my project, giving me error  and for second code is working but not effectively as its not showing all progress indicator. it shows one Rectangle only that is not moving in progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a few Overrides :)

I've heavily modified most of the common controls to get the look I'm after with a little XAML as possible.  Here's a cut and paste from a earlier progress bar I was using to meet what you want to do.

XAML Namespace

---

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
 xmlns:MyControl="clr-namespace:MyOverrideConrols"    
>
```

C# Progress Bar Override

---

```
namespace MyOverrideConrols
{
    public class MyProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {
        public MyProgressBar()
            : base()
        {
            this.NewDotSize = 20;
        }
        public MyProgressBar(int dot_size = 20)
            : base()
        {

            this.NewDotSize = (dot_size <= 0) ? 1 : dot_size;
        }

        public int NewDotSize{ get; set; }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            Rectangle slider_0 = (Rectangle)this.GetTemplateChild("Slider0"); ResizeRectangle(ref slider_0, NewDotSize);
            Rectangle slider_1 = (Rectangle)this.GetTemplateChild("Slider1"); ResizeRectangle(ref slider_1, NewDotSize);
            Rectangle slider_2 = (Rectangle)this.GetTemplateChild("Slider2"); ResizeRectangle(ref slider_2, NewDotSize);
            Rectangle slider_3 = (Rectangle)this.GetTemplateChild("Slider3"); ResizeRectangle(ref slider_3, NewDotSize);
            Rectangle slider_4 = (Rectangle)this.GetTemplateChild("Slider4"); ResizeRectangle(ref slider_4, NewDotSize);
            Rectangle slider_5 = (Rectangle)this.GetTemplateChild("Slider5"); ResizeRectangle(ref slider_5, NewDotSize);

        }

        private void ResizeRectangle(ref Rectangle rect, int new_size)
        {
            if (rect == null)
                return;
            rect.Width = new_size;
            rect.Height = new_size;
        }
    }
}
```

How To Use

---

```
<MyControl:MyProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Height="25" NewDotSize="20"></MyControl:MyProgressBar>
```

---

Progress Bar In Action

[image]