# How to change the size of the ProgressBar dots?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

They're too small.

I can change the colour easily enough with

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF0055A3" />
```

Unfortunately I can't see a way to change the size.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can reference from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459402/increase-size-of-dots-in-progress-bar-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried overriding these:

```
<x:Double x:Key="ProgressBarThemeMinHeight">3.5</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateRectagleThemeSize">3.5</x:Double>
```

EDIT: I thought this was an interesting question, so I decided to write a [blog post about it](http://igrali.com/2014/09/26/larger-progressbar-rectangles-on-windows-phone/).

Comment: I'll give that a try Monday morning.

Comment: Nice one, it worked. This is a novelty - I've never been the inspiration for someone else's blog post before!